# new added references not working from bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker

I am writing an article using latest version of TeXmaker and MiKTeX. I have previously saved incomplete report. Everything was working fine on old laptop and old versions of texmaker. I am using a bib file to add references of biblatex type. Old references are properly working even if I am citing them again in article, they are working fine but when I try to add a new reference, it does not work, I copy bibtex reference from Google Scholar and paste in bib file and cite in my article. Problem is only with new references.
The references show as [liu2019mid], [11], [nugrahaningsih2019soft], the middle one [11] is an old reference which was previously added in bib file and the other two are not showing properly and they are also not showing in bibliography.
This screenshot includes recently added two references.
[image]

Comment: You need to rerun LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX if you modify your `.bib` file or cite previously uncited entries. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. You may want to set up your editor to help you run Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: oh, yes, fixed, Thanks :)